# How to write a procedure that takes integer to string map and produces string to set of integers map

Tags: c++11

It is supposed to take an integer and string as a map and return string and set of integers as a map.
Say the input is (205 -> "ORD"
309 -> "ORD"); it returns ("ORD" -> {205,309}). Something like that.

```
map<int,string>myMap;

map<int,set<int>>setMap;
```

Comment: You need to use <> instead of () for template arguments.

Comment: `map<string, set<int>> itemsByName;` is probably what you want. Loop original data and fill target data. What is the problem?

Comment: Edited. I used brackets for my code. But I don't know how to continue the loop.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  However, your original question had no code and demonstrated a fundamental lack of understanding of C++ syntax ([using `()` instead of `<>` for template arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52574291/1)).  So it is not clear that your level of experience is enough to meaningfully process any answer you are given.  How are we to know you know how to write a loop at all?  Or what a main() function is?  You need to show yourself further along in the process (any process), and ask a question showing the actual point at which you are blocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::map<std::string,std::set<int>> func(const std::map<int,std::string>& input)
{
    std::map<std::string,std::set<int>> result;
    for(auto & iterm:input)
    {
        result[iterm.second].insert(iterm.first);
    }
    return result;
}
```